# How to find the item that its quantity of sale is greater than 1000 in 30 mins by using Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's assume the data has three fields:  itemID, timeStamp, totalQuantityOfSale.

Every 5 mins I want to report the items whose quantity of sale is greater than 1000 in the previous 30 mins.

What I am trying to do is

```
DataStream<String> process =  stream
                .keyBy(Item::getId)
                .timeWindow(Time.minutes(30), Time.minutes(5))
                .process(new MyProcessFunction());
```

In this MyProcessFunction(), I am thinking about storing the timeStamp and totalQuantityOfSale of the last data.
So

```
if(currentData.getTimeStamp()>lastTimeStamp){
    sum+=(currentData.getQuantityOfSale-lastTotalQuantityOfSale);
}
```

However, this MyProcessFunction should extend ProcessWindowFunction which needs lots of memories. And I also don't know this method is correct or not.
So can anyone tell me how to do it? Is there any other better solution?
Thank you very much!

Comment: The precise semantics of what you hope to accomplish aren't clear. Are you talking about a rolling 30 minute window, or are tumbling windows good enough? Are the 5 minute updates only desired while the 1000 threshold is exceeded?

Comment: Sorry for not clear. It should be: Every 5 minutes, output product IDs with sales increments greater than 1000 in the past 30 minutes. So I think I should use a sliding window.

Comment: Can you please explain the relationship of totalQuantityOfSale, lastTotalQuantityOfSale, the sum, and 1000? At first I thought it would be enough to compute the sum of totalQuantityOfSale across 30 mins, but apparently not. And why are you checking if `currentData.getTimeStamp()>lastTimeStamp`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for could be expressed in Flink SQL as

```sql
SELECT
  id, window_start, window_end, sum(quantityOfSale) AS totalQuantityOfSale
FROM TABLE(
  HOP(TABLE events, DESCRIPTOR(timeStamp), INTERVAL '5' MINUTES, INTERVAL '30' MINUTES))
GROUP BY
  id, window_start, window_end
HAVING sum(quantityOfSale) > 1000;
```